# “To repair something” vs “To get something repaired”

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

How is the phrase “**Get the car repaired**” different from “**Repair the car**”?
Is there a difference? If so, how do I use this?

For example:

[image: Get the car repaired]

[image: Get the vehicle resprayed]

Comment: The second picture has nothing to do with this question. And, discounting it, the first question doesn't serve as any kind of comparison between the different sentences.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don’t care what verb would be there. I need to get the basic idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Repair the car" suggests that you will do the job yourself.

"Get the car repaired" implies that you will pay someone else to do it.

Comment: got it, thank you. So, “get the car **broke**” or “**broken**”? I mean, what form of irregular verbs should I use in this construction, simple past or past participle?

Comment: Neither "get the car broke" nor "get the car broken" makes any sense to me as a native speaker. However, you could say "the glass got broken" (i.e. somebody else broke it, it wasn't me!)

Comment: Actually, "get the car broken" would make sense if you _want_ the car to be broken.